# Constrain method type argument to be base of class generic type

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I would like to ensure that method type argument is base type of class generic type so first I naturally wrote this:

```
public class FivePM<T> {
    public void drink<M>(M x) where T : M {}
}
```

Is there any specific reason why this can't work?

**Background**

I wrote container class `Bag<B>` which stores items shared between different instances, so an item is automatically removed from one bag if it's added to another. This is done internaly by the `BagSet<BT>` which hold bags for common items. I wanted for bag generic type to be the lowest common type of items in sets but don't want constrian `B` to be exactly `BT`but to any derived type.
I've managed to make type safe public interface for the bag fulfill my requirements but because of generic constrains limitations, bags construction looks awkward and I can't use list initializer:

```
BagSet<object> bset = new BagSet<object>();
Bag<int> suitcase = bset.newBag<int>();

public class BagSet<T> : BagSetBase {
    public Bag<B> newBag<B>(string name = null, params B[] items) where B : T {
        var b = new Bag<B>(this, name);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) b.Add(items[i]);
        return b;
    }
}
```

Are generic constrains going to be improved someday? Maybe I should wait before making such things extensively.

Comment: `Is there any specific reason why this can't work?` Yes, you have reversed T and M, it should be `where M : T`

Comment: Please explain what the actual problem is. The second code example you have looks like it ought to work fine. The first code example declares the constraint exactly opposite from what you say you want; it's not legal C#, but that shouldn't matter because it's not expressing anything you claim to want to be able to express in the generic type system. Your question isn't making any sense at the moment.

Comment: My point is that I want to do other way i.e. In my method I need `x` of any type `M` which is or derives from type `T` - the `FivePM` generic type. I know what I wrote, I'm just asking why its not possible :)

Comment: It isn't possible because the people who designed the C# language and wrote the compilers didn't put in the support for it. I have no idea if they thought about it, but nobody added support for that constraint, thus it isn't supported.

Comment: I was thinking maybe someone will tell it they had plans and no time or maybe it is very tricky to implement or something...

Comment: omg You are right, I was so concern to fit the title that I spell it wrong... twice. Of course I want `x` argument type to be base type for `T` which is `FivePM` generic type. Hope this makes sense now. sorry

Comment: @PawełAudionysos Out of curiosity, how are you handling the removal from one bag? I made my implementation (see my answer) using a `Dictionary<T,object>` in `BagSet` that associated items with bags and delegated most `Bag` operations to the `BagSet`.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos I think I am confused now. Perhaps if you showed the code that doesn't work as well as the code that does and were more consistent between your exposition and your code with your `BT`, `T`, `B`?

Comment: I mean complicated in terms of resulting interface. I believe it's more convenient to write `Bag<SomeType> x =` than  `Bag<SomeType, SomeOtherType> x =` The problem is I can't use standard constructor while having only single bag generic type and also bagset changing would not be possible without `BagSetBase` but that's another story... I don't know you downvoted I just asked one sentence question that I didn't found and given easiest example I could make. I don't know how is that worst than any other question on basic future which is described everywhere on the internet... :/

Comment: About item removal I took similar approach but mad a wrapper for the item. Here the link to complete code: http://www.mediafire.com/file/59mv66le6gk87ne/bags.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any specific reason why this can't work?

If you mean is there a *logical* reason why that kind of constraint doesn't make sense, then no.  That's a perfectly sensible constraint, and there are languages that support that sort of constraint. Java, for instance.  And Scala.

If you mean is there a reason why this doesn't work *in C#*, that's easy. **No one ever implemented that feature in C#.** In order for a feature to work in C#, someone has to think of it, design it, write a specification, implement the specification, write tests, and then ship it to customers.  Of those necessary steps, only the first one happened.

> Are generic constrains going to be improved someday?

Questions asking for a prediction of the future are off-topic on Stack Overflow. We have no ability to reliably predict the future.

If you'd like this feature to be in a future version of C#, consider advocating for it on the github forum.

Comment: Jon Skeet can tell the future... Twice! (Or was it count to infinity?)

Comment: Yes, but It's not like predicting the weather... I guess they don't throw dice to  decide what feature add next, someone has to know something... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using your real code, what if you made `class Bag` take two types and handle the inheritance requirement - after all, you don't care about that in a `BagSet`:

```
public class BagSet<T> {
    public Bag<B, T> newBag<B>(string name = null, params B[] items) where B : T {
        var b = new Bag<B, T>(this, name);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) b.Add(items[i]);
        return b;
    }
}

public class Bag<B, T> where B : T {
    BagSet<T> common;
    string bsname;

    public Bag(BagSet<T> bs, string name) {
        common = bs;
        bsname = name;
    }
    public void Add(B item) {
    }
}
```

Then you can declare them like so:

```
var bset = new BagSet<object>();
var suitcase = bset.newBag<int>();
```

Comment: Nice! Looks better then your original (and my) answer.

Comment: Those look the same but these are just more typing. My code is working so why should I complicate this even more? I purposely made `BagSetBase` abstract class so that `BagSet` can manage Bags internally while `Bag<T>` keeps type safe interface. I think bag should not care of what set it is in. Also I'm not sure I could later change bagset of a bag if other bagset had different type. If you want to take a look I can show whole code tomorrow, but thanks for attention anyway :)

Comment: @PawełAudionysos You asked the question? I am not sure I follow how this is more complicated? In the `Bag` constructor, what is the type of the first parameter (passed as `this` from `BagSet.newBag`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to get this working:

```
public class FivePM<T, M> where T : M 
{
    public void drink(M x) 
}
```

But then again your question confused me and it is past midnight here so I might be wrong and I might misunderstood the question.... Or maybe not?